# How can I print a string in a loop (10,100, 1000 cycles) using multiple threads (2, 4,8 , 16 threads) with no synchronization?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I need to write a program that will print characters onto console. The threads need not be synchronized, which means that the data will be mixed and the output should be messy. However, my output works fine and it seems like I'm doing something wrong.

```
typedef struct {
    std::string info;
    unsigned int m_number;
    unsigned m_cycles;
    unsigned m_currentThread;
}data;

unsigned int __stdcall Func(void* d) {
    data* real = (data*)d;
    std::cout << "Current thread ID: " << GetCurrentThreadId() << std::endl;
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = (real->m_currentThread - 1) * real->m_cycles / real->m_number;j < real->m_currentThread * real->m_cycles / real->m_number;j++) {
        std::cout << real->info << std::endl;
        }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int threadsNumber;
    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    std::cout << "Enter the number of threads:\n";
    std::cin >> threadsNumber;
    int cycles;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of cycles:\n";
    std::cin >> cycles;
    std::vector<HANDLE> threads;
    HANDLE tmp;
    data* args = new data;
    args->info = str;
    args->m_number = threadsNumber;
    args->m_cycles = cycles;
    for (int i = 1;i <= threadsNumber;++i) {
        args->m_currentThread = i;
        tmp = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &Func, args, 0, 0);
        Sleep(1000L);
        threads.push_back(tmp);
    }
    WaitForMultipleObjects(threads.size(), &threads.front(), TRUE, INFINITE);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be character-wise and the strings should get messy, since there's no synchronization between the threads yet.

Comment: `cout` has it's own synchronization.  Two calls won't interleave and thread1: `cout << "foo";` thread2: `cout << "bar";` will only give you `"foobar"` or `"barfoo"`.

Comment: Unrelated: If you are using C++11 or later, you could use the standard `std::thread` and friends instead of Windows specific functions.

Comment: My guess is `Sleep(1000L)` is letting your threads finish execution before you start the next one. Why not start them all immediately?

Comment: Thank you, Nathan, for your comment, it's really helpful.  Do you know whether there is another function I could use?

Comment: Yes, I know that C++11 supports multithreading, but this is my college task and I am allowed to use WinAPI functions only.

Comment: There is `printf`.  I don't think it synchronizes but I'm not sure.  You could also write you own print function for string that prints character by character to get them to try an interleave.

Comment: I think `cout` is what you want, despite what Nathan said. Unless the goal is for it to print `foo` and `bar` as `foboaro`, you can use `cout` for asynchronous console outputs.

Comment: @anastasiia_kos You are using `std::vector` and that's not a WinAPI function. It's a class in the standard library, just as `std::thread` is. Just saying...

Comment: _"I am allowed to use WinAPI functions only"_. But `getchar()` is not WinAPI.

Comment: you need remove `Sleep(1000L);` and use different arguments for different threads. this is main. also be good create notification event - and all threads initial begin wait for this event. then main thread - set this event - and all working threads start almost synchronously

Comment: I need to use WinAPI function to create threads. Other things like input and output can be standard C/C++ functions.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! alteredinstance and RbMm comments gave me the right solution. I removed Sleep  and now everything works as it should be.)

Comment: `unsigned int __stdcall Func(void* d) ` - you are trying *too hard*. Why on earth is this not just `unsigned int Func(void* d)`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl - because thread entry point must be `__stdcall`. so you need or set `/Gz` option or use explicit `__stdcall`

Comment: I'm using _beginthreadex function and if I remove __stdcall I get an error: argument of type "unsigned int (*)(void *d)" is incompatible with parameter of type "_beginthreadex_proc_type"

Comment: Re, "the output should be messy." That might be harder than you think depending on what you think "messy" means and, on what you think "should" means. When your program creates multiple threads, that _allows_ things to happen concurrently. If you don't provide any synchronization when they access a shared resource, then you are _allowing_ them to access it in any order; and that include patterns of use that might not look "messy."  If you want to _enforce_ certain rules, (e.g., no thread ever gets to write more than three characters in a row) then you'll have to express those rules in code.

Answer (score 1):

> The output should be character-wise and the strings should get messy

This is not backed by the contract of [`std::cout`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout):

> Unless `sync_with_stdio(false)` has been issued, it is safe to concurrently access these objects from multiple threads for both formatted and unformatted output.

The observed behavior matches the expected behavior.